# What is the usefulness of "Wrapper around Supabase.js" in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, wrapper, vue-composition-api, supabase

- https://github.com/supabase-community/vue-supabase

I've seen a few of these ^ Vue wrappers for Supabase, but I have not seen an explanation as to why one would want to use them.
Can someone point me to what the differences are or even better, why using `vue-supabase` is better?

---

Why is doing...

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useSupabase } from "vue-supabase";

const supabase = useSupabase();

const { data, error } = await supabase.from("events").select("*");
</script>
```

better than doing...

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { supabase } from "../supabase";

const { data, error } = await supabase.from("events").select("*");
</script>
```

?

*I apologize ahead of time if the answer here is simple and I just missed it.*

Comment: It could be helpful if you have multiple instances per project, which is a rare but existing. Otherwise it's just a useless abstraction.

Comment: @EstusFlask thank you for your response. Follow-up question, might you have any idea how big (pages/components) you would need to justify using it?

Comment: By it you mean Supabase? I don't use it, but it's more about the case and the way you need to handle data and other features it can help with, not just a size. You can use it on any pet project to try it in action.